# Отправка AT команд через USB OTG

Tags: android, usb, terminal, at

Нужно отправить AT команду через USB OTG на устройство.
Для теста использовал UsbTerminal, все команды успешно отрабатываются.

В моём приложении нужно сделать по сути такой же терминал.

Что я уже сделал:

1. Нахожу устройство подключённое по USB к моему девайсу:
2. Получаю **DeviceID, VendorID** и другие его параметры.

Код

```
manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
        ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
String i = "";
while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
    device = deviceIterator.next();
    manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
    i += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + device.getDeviceId() + "\n"
            + "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() + "\n"
            + "DeviceClass: " + device.getDeviceClass() + " - "
            + "DeviceSubClass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n"
            + "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() + "\n"
            + "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n"
            + "DeviceProtocol: " + device.getDeviceProtocol() + "\n"
            + "Interface: " + device.getInterface(0) + "\n";

    textInfo.setText(i);
}
```

**Получаю интерфейс и ендпоинт:**

```
UsbInterface usbInterface = device.getInterface(0);
UsbEndpoint usbEndpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(0);
```

Далее я так понимаю что нужно открыть подключение к девайсу:

```
UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true);
```

**И передать ему команду:**

```
String setData = "AT";
byte[] bytesVar = setData.getBytes();

connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, bytesVar, bytesVar.length, TIMEOUT);
```

**Сам BroadcastReceiver:**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                        UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        // call method to set up device communication
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Вопрос, как получить ответ от устройства? Предполагаю что нужно использовать **controlTransfer**

Comment: Вообще то подобные команды передаются через симулятор com порта. Можно ли передать так, как  в Вашем коде - я не знаю. Но одно знаю точно - в конце команды нужно добавить перевод строки - он является признаком окончания команды.

Comment: Я пользовался библиотекой MLA из MPLAB x IDE фирмы Microchip.
Там есть куча примеров с исходным кодом для программирования девайса и хоста, соединённых по каналу usb.